# Is it better to alphabetize or group similar property names?

Tags: .net, code-formatting, code-organization

What I am asking is if you alphabetize your properties or group them. Example:

**Grouping**

```
Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property CustomerID As Integer
Public Property Address As Address
Public Property Name As Integer
```

**Alpha**

```
Public Property Address As Address
Public Property CustomerID As Integer
Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property Name As Integer
```

Comment: Could you try clarifying your question a bit more? Do you mean how do you retrieve the properties on an object and put them in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of where they physically are in a code file? I prefer alphabetization, but most of the time it's hardly a concern anyways since there is a convenient drop down of members available in the code editor.

Comment: Yeah, in the actual code file, I was thinking of alphabetizing because it is easier to find if you have a lot of properties. Just wondering though...

Answer (score 1):

I generally arrange properties in groups, not alphabetically. For instance:

```
Contact
    ID
    FirstName
    LastName
    Address
    City
    State
    CountryID
    PostalCode
```

Comment: But it doesn't matter too much!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully your class won't be big enough to care either way.  However, I would arrange them by groups (commenting the reason for grouping in each section, then alphabetically within each group.